# Clojure with Leiningen: how to get local dependencies included?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am working on learning Clojure through the **Programming Clojure** book but stuck early trying to get an example from the book working.

I downloaded the code examples from the book; the directory structure is

```
examples/
```

and there are a bunch of .clj files in there including one called **introduction.clj**.

The code I'm trying to run starts with

`(require 'examples/introduction')`

... but I can't get this to work.

I've tried adding a **checkouts** directory and symlinking the examples directory in there.
I've tried making a .jar file with a Manifest.txt giving it version 1.0.0 ....

But running

`lein repl`

so far always gives errors, like

> Could not find artifact examples:introduction:jar:1.0.0 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
> Could not find artifact examples:introduction:jar:1.0.0 in clojars (https://repo.clojars.org/)
> This could be due to a typo in :dependencies, file system permissions, or network issues.

The **project.clj** file is like this:

```
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "EPL-2.0 OR GPL-2.0-or-later WITH Classpath-exception-2.0"
            :url "https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"]
                 [clj-http "2.0.0"]
         [examples/introduction "1.0.0"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot my-stuff.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all
                       :jvm-opts ["-Dclojure.compiler.direct-linking=true"]}})
```

What am I missing? Thanks much for any guidance whatsoever!

Comment: There is :source-paths param in project.clj . You may want to give it a try

Comment: Source-paths worked! Thanks! I must have missed this in the docs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated project.clj file after the helpful comment by leetwinski:

```
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "EPL-2.0 OR GPL-2.0-or-later WITH Classpath-exception-2.0"
            :url "https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"]
                 [clj-http "2.0.0"]]
  :source-paths ["/home/mark/src/cloj/code/src/examples"]
  :main ^:skip-aot my-stuff.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all
                       :jvm-opts ["-Dclojure.compiler.direct-linking=true"]}})
```